# Given a finite group, does this equation involving group's order, a partition of it and centralizers' orders hold?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with $|G|=n$. In the case $Z(G)=\lbrace e \rbrace$, the following equation seems to hold:

\begin{equation}
n(n-1)=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|C_G(a)|-1)+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}|C_G(a)|^2([G:C_G(a)]-1)
\end{equation}

where $C_G(a)$ is the centralizer of $a$ in $G$ and $\lambda(n-1)$ is a partition of the integer $n-1$.

Before anyone wastes time going through my proof's sketch, can some more trained eye than mine acknowledge at a glance whether above equation is:

1. trivial (e.g. an identity);
2. correct and well-known;
3. clearly wrong.

Comment: With $G=S_3$, I am getting $42$ for the third term in the sum, which is already bigger than $n(n-1)=30$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll double check my proof's sketch.

Comment: Surely that can't be true for **all** partitions, since different partitions should give you different results for the first term...

Comment: @Arnaud D. Not really, you're right; but indeed I was (and still am) hoping such a partition to be "characteristic" of $G$ itself.

Comment: @Derek Holt. Although I'm still quite confident on 1st and 2nd term, you're right: the 3rd one is completely wrong and I'm working to thoroughly revise it.