# Given a finite group, does this equation involving group's order, a partition of it and centralizers' orders hold?_Attempt#2

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

After failing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3070935/given-a-finite-group-does-this-equation-involving-groups-order-a-partition-of) attempt, I've revised my proof sketch and I've come to the following version of the equation in the title.

So, let $G$ be a finite group, say $G=\lbrace e,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1} \rbrace$, and $C_G(a_i)$ denote the centralizer of $a_i$ in $G$. Then, in the case $Z(G)=\lbrace e \rbrace$, the following equation seems to hold:

\begin{equation}
n(n-1)=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\delta(\Lambda)_j|C_G(a_j)|
\end{equation}

where $\delta(\Lambda)$ is a $(n-1)$-term partition of the integer $\Lambda:=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$, being $\lambda(n-1)$ a partition of the integer $n-1$.

*E.g.*, for $G=S_3$, if we take $\lambda(5)=(2,3)$ and $\delta(13)=(2,2,3,3,3)$, we get:
\begin{equation}
6\cdot5 = 2^2+3^2+2\cdot(3-1)+2\cdot(3-1)+3\cdot(2-1)+3\cdot(2-1)+3\cdot(2-1)
\end{equation}

As I'm not very skilled on symmetric groups, can someone check whether above formula works also for $S_4$, etc. or some other group with trivial center?

---

*Proof.*

Let's define the collections $F_a:=(\varphi_g(a))_{g\in G}$, where $\varphi_g(a):=g^{-1}ag$, and denote by $\tilde F_a$ the set composed of the *distinct* elements of $F_a$. We have:

1. $\forall a \in G, a \in \tilde F_a$; then, $\tilde F_a \ne \emptyset$;
2. $\forall a \in G, |F_a|=n$;
3. $\tilde F_e=\lbrace e \rbrace$;
4. $Z(G)=\lbrace e \rbrace \Rightarrow |\tilde F_a|>1, \forall a \in G, a \ne e$;
5. $F_a=(\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in C_G(a)} \cup (\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}=(a,a,...,a) \cup (\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}$, with $|(a,a,...,a)|=|C_G(a)|$;
6. given $a,b \in G, b \ne a$, it is $\tilde F_b=\tilde F_a \Leftrightarrow b \in \tilde F_a$;
7. the collection $(\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}$ contains as many *copies* of *each* element $b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$ as is the cardinality of the set $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}:=\lbrace g \in \complement_G(C_G(a))|\varphi_g(a)=b \rbrace$, *minus* $1$.

We may also think of a $n \times n$ "matrix" such that, given $a \in G$, the "$a$-th" row is made of the elements of the set $\lbrace \varphi_a(g)|g \in G \rbrace$ and the "$a$-th" column is made of the elements of the collection $F_a=(\varphi_g(a))_{g \in G}$. According to this "picture", we have that:

- for 3 and 4, there's one and only one column with *all* the entries equal to each other (all $e$);
- for 5, the "$a$-th" column contains as many *copies* of $a$ as the order of $C_G(a)$, *minus* $1$;
- for 6 and 7, there are $|\tilde F_a|$ columns with the same, differently permuted, $|\tilde F_a|$ distinct elements (included the "index" $a$); each of these columns has as many *copies* of each element $b$ of $\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$ as is the integer $|\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}|-1$.

Now, $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow b \notin \tilde F_a$, and then $b \in \tilde F_a \Rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)} \ne \emptyset \Rightarrow |\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}|=|C_G(a)|$ (for the last implication, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071838/how-many-g-in-a-finite-group-are-such-that-b-g-1ag-for-given-a-ne-b-in/3071918#3071918)).

By summing on all the columns, we have that a partition $\lambda(n-1)$ of the integer $n-1$ exists such that:

\begin{align}
n^2& = n+\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|C_G(a)|-1)+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\sum_{b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace}(|\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}|-1)=\\&=n+\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|C_G(a)|-1)+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|(|C_G(a)|-1)=\\&=n+\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1)(|C_G(a)|-1)
\end{align}

But, $$\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1)=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$$

so, if we define $\delta_a:=|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1$, we get:

\begin{equation}
n(n-1) = \sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\delta_a(|C_G(a)|-1)
\end{equation}

with $$\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\delta_a=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$$

and then, for a given labelling of the elements of $G$,

\begin{equation}
n(n-1)=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\delta(\Lambda)_j|C_G(a_j)|
\end{equation}

where $\delta(\Lambda)$ is a $(n-1)$-term partition of the integer $\Lambda:=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$.

---

### Addendum

As shown, each $a \in G$, $a \ne e$, gives rise to the collection $F_a$ made of:

- $|\tilde F_a|$ distinct elements of $G$, included $a$;
- $|C_G(a)|-1$ copies of $a$;
- $|\mathcal{F}_b^{(a)}|-1=|C_G(a)|-1$ copies of $b$, for each $b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$.

Then, 
\begin{align}
n=&|\tilde F_a|+|C_G(a)|-1+(|C_G(a)|-1)(|\tilde F_a|-1)=\\=&|\tilde F_a|+|C_G(a)|-1+|C_G(a)||\tilde F_a|-|C_G(a)|-|\tilde F_a|+1=\\=&|C_G(a)||\tilde F_a|
\end{align}

so $|\tilde F_a|=[G:C_G(a)]$, and finally $$\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}[G:C_G(a)]=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$$

*For a finite group of order $n$ and trivial center, a partition $\lambda(n-1)$ of $n-1$ with no "1" summands exists, such that the sum of the indexes of the centralizers of all the elements of the group (but the unit) is equal to the sum of the squares of the summands of $\lambda(n-1)$.*

Comment: I don't see how something like this could possibly work, as the sum on the right depends on the ordering of the elements of $G$. For example, even for $S_3$ and $\lambda(5)=(2,3)$, this fails if we order the elements of $S_3$ differently. (For example, if $a_1$ is an involution rather than an element of order $3$.)

Comment: Wouldn't in that case the equation hold with, *e.g.*, the partition $\delta(13)=(3,2,3,3,2)$ ?

Comment: Do you have any clue how to find a partition that will work? 
If not, then it seems hard computationally to check whether it holds for a given group (and it could also hold for trivial reasons, simply because there are so many partitions). Moreover, if not, then it seems hard to use the result, since we wouldn't know what the partition is.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, my proof simply states that such partitions $\lambda$ and $\delta$ do exist, no more than that. If it were correct, I'm more inclined to think that, as you argued, it is simply for trivial reasons. So, I think I'd better to post the sketch of the proof for your review.

Comment: Edited with my proof attempt.